# Android SQLite error on open

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i'm having a problem in SQLite i followed the tutorial of travis but still I got error and iv'e been trying for a few days can someone please help me thanks in advance.

Here's my codes

**LOGCAT**

```
10-17 16:21:57.835: D/AndroidRuntime(2238): Shutting down VM
10-17 16:21:57.835: W/dalvikvm(2238): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.sqlite/com.sample.sqlite.SQLite}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.sample.sqlite.SQLite.onCreate(SQLite.java:28)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-17 16:21:57.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     ... 11 more
```

**JAVA**
    package com.sample.sqlite;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLite extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnUpdate, btnView;
    EditText etName, etScore, etCleared;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etScore);
        etCleared = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCleared);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (arg0.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnUpdate:

            boolean didItWork = true;
            try{
            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String score = etScore.getText().toString();
            String cleared = etCleared.getText().toString();

            Score entry = new Score(SQLite.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name, score, cleared);
            entry.close();

            }catch (Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Yup");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btnView:

            break;
        }
    }


}
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.sqlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SQLite"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SQLITE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sample.sqlite.SQLite.onCreate(SQLite.java:28)` ... maybe you didn't provide the context in there?

Answer (score 2):

you are not setting the contentView

add  **setContentView()**

Comment: I did add setContentView on my SQLite.java but still got the error